# windows 10 - permission denied when trying to delete folder

Tags: windows-10

I have a certain folder on my computer that I want to delete but I can't. I opened the cmd console as administrator and tried to delete the folder, but access was denied. It doesn't even let me change ownership on the folder. I'm using windows 10 64-bit. How can I delete the folder?

Thanks.

Comment: I have run into this problem too.  there is usually a hidden .thumbnail file in the directory and windows keeps claiming its in use despite having deleted every other file in the directory.

Comment: I enabled hidden files but didn't see it. Did you manage to solve the problem?

Comment: Not that I recall I usually got distracted by something else.  Have you tried rebooting?  rebooting to a safe mode then deleting it from there?

Answer (score 3):

Try Lock Hunter , its a unlocker software which worked well for me

Answer (score 1):

1. open power shell as administrator
2. `cd c:\folderInQuestion`
3. `rm -r .\folderInQuestion\`

Answer (score 0):

If the folder lies outide of your specific User Account folder, then you will have to take ownership of the folder (or a parent folder) before you can delete it.

In my case, I needed to delete a subfolder that was nested deep inside my Projects folder, which sits at my root. Even though my account had "full control" (see [this](https://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/forum/windows_10-files/access-denied-windows-10/2a5429ee-dc93-4095-8058-a5ecfd2b69c9))

To take ownership of the folder, follow this: https://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/forum/windows_10-files/give-permissions-to-files-and-folders-in-windows/78ee562c-a21f-4a32-8691-73aac1415373